# Finding the shortest distance of two points and an area

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions, mesh, distance

So I have a region defined by something like `MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1/2}, {2, -1/2}}, {Line[{1, 2}], Line[{2, 3}], Line[{3, 4}], Line[{4, 1}]}]`, and two points like `Point[{1,2}]` and `Point[{5,5}]` .
Then I want to find a path which goes from one point to the region and then to the other point, and find the shortest one among all those possible paths.
I have an idea of starting at a random point, then move the point along the region, towards the direction where the distance is shorter. If I start on an arbitrary large amount of points, then I can expect the best solution.
However, I don't know how to move a point around a region, not to mention measuring each step. Is there a way to do so?

So as a update, I hope that this works with geo positions as well.

Comment: with `mr = MeshRegion[...]`, `NMinimize[{ArcLength[Line@{{1, 2}, {x, y}, {5, 5}}], 
  RegionDistance[mr, {x, y}] == 0}, {x, y}]` gives `{6.65685, {x -> 1., y -> 1.}}`

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:graphs-and-networks]?